# I am not getting HTTP method from event of lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services

This is my event object.

```
2023-07-17T09:23:21.102Z    417bd641-b182-4b6f-b4c3-6fc39a81f594    INFO    
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "routeKey": "$default",
    "rawPath": "/",
    "rawQueryString": "",
    "headers": {
        "x-amzn-tls-cipher-suite": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "x-amzn-tls-version": "TLSv1.2",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-64b50889-766dec4c58bf5b332f424218",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
        "host": "i3xxbbcdnd6xunba6euxom7n6m0lohjs.lambda-url.ap-south-1.on.aws",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-for": "49.36.81.218",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "user-agent": "Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)"
    },
    "requestContext": {
        "accountId": "anonymous",
        "apiId": "i3xxbbcdnd6xunba6euxom7n6m0lohjs",
        "domainName": "i3xxbbcdnd6xunba6euxom7n6m0lohjs.lambda-url.ap-south-1.on.aws",
        "domainPrefix": "i3xxbbcdnd6xunba6euxom7n6m0lohjs",
        "http": {
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/",
            "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
            "sourceIp": "49.36.81.218",
            "userAgent": "Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)"
        },
        "requestId": "417bd641-b182-4b6f-b4c3-6fc39a81f594",
        "routeKey": "$default",
        "stage": "$default",
        "time": "17/Jul/2023:09:23:21 +0000",
        "timeEpoch": 1689585801077
    },
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

I am using this statement to access the requested method.....

```
const method = await event.requestContext.http.method;
```

And I am getting this error

```
"errorType": "TypeError",
"errorMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'http')",
```

I have tried many ways to access this method to perform my operation. but unfortunate I failed to achieve desired output.

This my actual code....

```
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
  const method = JSON.stringify(event.requestContext.http.method);
  console.log(method);
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: method,
  };
}
```

And This is the full error......

```
2023-07-17T09:33:22.176Z    c51956ea-a811-475d-b7ed-8c83b17bc2bf    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'http')",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'http')",
        "    at module.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:6:54)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1086:29)"
    ]
}
```

I have updated my logged event and actual error with actual code.

The strange thing is that when I am running this code in the aws console, it is throwing the error which I have mention but if I am running this code in the vs code thunder client it is giving the correct output. How is it possible. And if I log the http method in cloudWatch it is also giving correct output there. I am attaching the both screenshot.

[Testing in AWS console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9roMz.png)

[Testing in Thunder Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uhNi.png)

Comment: What is your actual code? Why is there an `await` there? Did you log the actual event coming in?

Comment: I have added the actual code and error. And which object I have added that is logged event.

Comment: It doesn't look like that event would cause that error. Is that a log of the actual event received by the Lambda function?

Comment: @jarmod Firstly I have added event what I have got from browser after running the lambda function. But now I have added the actual logged event from the cloudWatch. Thanks.

Comment: I would assume that the event is presented to the Lambda function in a different form each time. You've logged the event you receive from the working VS Code client. How does it differ from the failing event you're sending as a test from the AWS console?

Comment: Thanks Mr. @jarmod for giving the time for this post. I am new to AWS. So I don't know  much more about that. Some event attributes can be different  sometime. But the position of 'method' in event is same each time in the Thunder Client, Browser and cloudWatch. Even it is working in thunder client but not in aws console.

Comment: In the failing testcase, log the value of `event.requestContext`. What is it? I presume it's undefined which means that requestContext is not a property of event and the sample event you've shown above is not representative of what's being passed into your Lambda function as the `event` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

We are missing some context about the source of the event that triggers the Lambda however, it seems that you are not converting to JSON the event before accessing its fields. Depending on the trigger's configuration, and that information is missing in your question, your Lambda function could be receiving exactly one event or an array of events (with at least one event).

If is a single event you can print it in this way: `console.log(JSON.stringify(event));` you can access the field in this way `const method = JSON.parse(event.requestContext.http.method)`

If instead the print shows a structure like this one:

```
{
   "Records":[
        {
             your_event_body_here
        }
   ]
}
```

then the event object is an array and you must iterate over it, for example using the `.map()` function :

```
event.Records.map(record =>{
 const single_event = JSON.parse(record)
 console.log("HTTP method is " + single_event.requestContext.http.method
 // your code here
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mr. Gabriele for your valuable response. But with the same code I am getting the output in browser but aws console, I am getting error which mention in my question.  According to your response, I tried this => const method = JSON.stringify(event.Records); and return the typeof method. It gave undefined as output.

Comment: Could you please add to the original answer the output of the command `console.log(JSON.stringify(event))`, I am having trouble understanding what the issue is. Thanks

Comment: I have added actual code, actual logged event and actual error Mr. Gabriele. Thanks.

Comment: @ShivamDubey in the question you edited there is still an error. As stated in my answer you shoud l use JSON.parse instead of JSON.stringify in your Lambda function code when you store the value in the new variable:  `const method = JSON.parse(event.requestContext.http.method)`. Probably you receive a type error since you are storing the variable `const method` as a string. 
The issue derives from the type of event that is sent when you perform the test from AWS console but, as stated before, on that we have no information.